# Does an IContainerConfigurator implementation exist that supports Enterprise Library 5 and Windsor Container 3.0?

Tags: castle-windsor, enterprise-library

I'm attempting to use Castle Windsor 3.0 (because I want to use the WcfFacility) and Enterprise Library 5.  I understand that I need to configure a Windsor specific IContainerConfigurator but have been unable to find one that works with CW 3.

The code [here](https://github.com/moodmosaic/WindsorContainerConfigurator/blob/master/dotNet35/WindsorContainerConfigurator/WindsorContainerConfigurator.cs) comes close but doesn't compile with CW 3.

Any ideas how to modify that code to support v3?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe there is one http://nuget.org/packages/EntLibContrib.Common.Configuration.Windsor/ although I have no idea how to use it.

Comment: It seems the link above is no longer available.  There is however a Castle Windsor Configurator for EntLib5 on Nuget which is supposed to work for CW >= 2.5.  I was unable to get this to compile when using CW >= 3.0 though.

Comment: @Mark. I'm afraid I don't really know as I haven't tried the code myself.